# I am able to get else part of the code, Else part is not working

Tags: python, flask, tortoise-orm

I am working on this code of logging in to the application. I can see that only if statement is working in this code for the valid values of username and password. If i enter the invalid values of username and password the else part should work, But it's not working.

```
**main.py**

@app.post("/loginsuccess/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_success(request: Request, username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    p = await User_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(await User.get(username=username, password=password))
    json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(p)
    if json_compatible_item_data['username']==username and json_compatible_item_data['password']==password:
        
        print(json_compatible_item_data["username"], "22222222222222222")
        return templates.TemplateResponse("homepage.html", {"request": request, "username":username})
    else:
        print("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO")
        status_code:int
        status_code = 500
        return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request":request, "status_code":status_code})
```

Answer (score 2):

[`from_tortoise_orm` returns a `pydantic` object](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/blob/9c5be496cc34e5684ff8af24f3f77f2c6a951068/tortoise/contrib/pydantic/base.py#L63) which is never `None` because an instance of a class is always a non-None object(unless you override the `__eq__` behaviour in the class definition).

Instead of comparing the the object `p`, you can try comparing `jsonable_encoder(p)`:

```
json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(p)
if json_compatible_item_data:
    print(json_compatible_item_data["username"], "22222222222222222")
    ...
else:
    print("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO")
    ...
```

**Update(based on OP's comment)**

You can do

```
if not json_compatible_item_data.get('detail') == 'Object does not exist':
    ...
else:
    print("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO")
    ...
```

Comment: How to fix this ?

Comment: Shiva, I tried it ! Its not working....getting the same result !!! else part is not working

Comment: @SagabarnisaS print the value of `json_compatible_item_data` when you expect the `else` clause to execute, what value do you see?

Comment: I am getting this in the browser {"detail":"Object does not exist"}

Comment: I have updated the answer, you may still have to handle additional values in the json/dict that determine whether your request was a success or not.

Comment: You mean i have get the username and password values of json and compare it ?

Comment: Hi @Shiva, I have updated my question by comparing the json values..but i am still not getting it. Please have a check

Comment: @SagabarnisaS Why are using checking username and password? In order to check if the request was a success or not, first you have to check for any relevant keys in `json_compatible_item_data`. In your case, that key seemed to be `detail`. You just have to check for the presence and value of that key and that's what I did in my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a expert of Django or Flask, but I think using `is not` is making it not work use `!= None`